# C++14 Template enable_if return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I have the following code witch takes an value and returns a random value between 0 and that value:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value>::type
RandomGenerator::random(T value) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> dist(0, value);
    return dist(RandomGenerator::mt);
}
```

my problem here is that the return type is void and i wanted it to be T.

the enable_if is there to avoid another function similar to this one but uses the std::uniform_int_distribution for integral types wich also has the same problem.

How can i write a function that can run the following example code:

```
auto BaseAngle = 10.0f;
//add a bit of randomness to the angle
BaseAngle += RandomGenerator::random(45.0f);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation!  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: If you're using C++14 then you can use `std::enable_if_t<...>` instead of `typename std::enable_if<...>::type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, T>
```

to make the type defined be `T` rather than `void`.